# Weather forecast applet for Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, desktop-environment, weather

## Background

Prior to [cycling to work](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/4484/im-a-cyclist-how-can-i-know-what-time-it-might-rain-how-likely-it-is-to-rain) in the morning, I'd like to know if I need to cart rain gear for the way home.

The xfce4-weather-plugin sits in the lower-right hand corner of the panel and is *almost* perfect:

[image: xfce4-weather-plugin screen shot, showing a sun]

Similarly, [My Weather Indicator](https://launchpad.net/my-weather-indicator) cannot show the evening forecast by default, nor does it appear to be configurable as a panel indicator. Also, it's gigantic (even on the 'small' setting) and draggable.

[image: My Weather Indicator screen shot, showing a sun]

## Problem

The problem is that these tools show the *current* weather, which offers the same information as *looking out the window*. Extra time is required to show the daily forecast, including what to expect for the evening.

There is no way to configure it to show the evening forecast by default instead of the current conditions.

## Question

What applet (or plug-in) can be customized to display:

- a raincloud icon in the panel if the day is expected to end in showers (partly cloudy, etc.)?
- the probability of precipitation (also for the evening)?
- using a small amount of screen real estate (e.g., ~70x50 pixels)?

Note that a panel indicator or applet, specifically, is sought.

Comment: If you use a web browser a lot, a weather extension / add-on may be another option

Answer (score 1):

[Conky](https://github.com/brndnmtthws/conky) is a nearly-infinitely configurable system monitor that could be set to display weather. It should be in Ubuntu's default repositories (maybe universe or multiverse).

There's even some built-in weather display options, here's a section from `man conky`:

> `weather URI locID data_type (interval_in_minutes)`
>
> Download, parse and display METAR data.
>
> For the 'URI', there are two possibilities:
>
> http://weather.noaa.gov/pub/data/observations/metar/stations/
>   http://xoap.weather.com/weather/local/
>
> The  first  one is free to use but the second requires you to register
>   and obtain your partner ID and license key. These two must be
>   written, separated  by a  space,  into  a file called .xoaprc which
>   needs to be placed into your home directory.
>
> 'locID' must be a valid location identifier for the required uri. For
>   the NOAA site   this   must   be   a   valid   ICAO   (see   for 
>   instance  https://pilotweb.nas.faa.gov/qryhtml/icao/). For the
>   weather.com site  this  must  be  a valid location ID (see for
>   instance http://aspnetresources.com/tools/locid.as‐ px).

So for example, this should show the current temperature at LAX (KLAX) and update every 10min:

`${weather http://weather.noaa.gov/pub/data/observations/metar/stations/ KLAX temperature 10}`

> `weather_forecast URI locID day data_type (interval_in_minutes)`
>
> Download, parse and display weather forecast data for a given day
>   (daytime on‐ ly).
>
> For  the 'URI', for the time being only
>   http://xoap.weather.com/weather/local/ is supported. See 'weather'
>   above for details of usage

---

If the above doesn't work perfectly, then a pre-made theme/script should, like https://github.com/zagortenay333/Harmattan
(From [How to add the town name to the conky Harmattan configuration?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/475189/how-to-add-the-town-name-to-the-conky-harmattan-configuration))

Or this one could work: https://github.com/zagortenay333/conky-Vision
(Found from [this answer on unix&linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116539/how-to-detect-the-desktop-environment-in-a-bash-script))
[image]

There's is a super-long forum thread on ubuntuforums.org [Conky weather scripts using Accuweather/WUnderground/NWS/Weather.com](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1156383&s=6b5ba2abaa8e795252c3c2b4f9ea50e6) but I wouldn't go near it without a search engine.

Just googling [conky weather script](https://encrypted.google.com/#q=conky+weather+script) should be great.

Comment: Can Conky integrate as a panel indicator?

Comment: @DaveJarvis there's a "panel" window type, to make conky act like a panel, the man page says "Panel windows reserve
              space along a desktop edge, just like panels and  taskbars,  preventing  maximized windows from overlapping them". Or one of the "own_window_type"'s may be able to stay on top of a part of an already existing panel, I think each window manager has different settings that could work

Comment: Thanks, Xen. I'm not looking to emulate another panel on the desktop. My desktop already has two panels. I'm looking for something that integrates with the existing panel. For example, if the existing panel has an auto-hide setting, Conky wouldn't necessarily hide when the existing panel hides, but would have to be configured independently?

Comment: Not sure about auto-hide, conky has a bunch of different window settings though it may depend on the window manager too. I use it to display everything "on the desktop", if there's a slice of desktop anywhere you can look at or uncover to check.